# CKEditor 4.3.2 - injecting DOM?

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to implement CKEditor v4.3.2. The way our product is set up is there are multiple areas of our pages that can be edited - we open an editor in a modal window and use the iframe method for editing. It works great with one exception:

If the page DOM looked something like  "body > div#container > div > div#editcontent"

and there was CSS rules targeting that DOM then the CSS does not apply in the editor because the editor DOM is simply "body"

What I would LIKE to do is supply the editor with the HTML DOM Structure of the page that holds the editor so the ContentCSS rules that normally impact the div would still apply (e.g. white background in the div instead of background color from the body tag)

I am at a loss for how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content of editor to inherit styles of your page, so a full integration with all the styles applied with every kind of selector, then you would have to use inline editing. Only inline editing offers that.

When using classic editor (the one using `iframe`) you still have an option though. It's the [`config.bodyClass`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-bodyClass) setting which lets you assign a class to the `body` element into which contents is loaded. Then, if all your contents styles selectors starts with that class and a stylesheet is loaded using the [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) setting, the content inside editor will look similarly to your final page.